# How to use generic types in mvc model view

Tags: c#, generics, model, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I want to create a partial view which will be used several times with differents entities.

It seems that the way to do that is to implement interfaces and use generic types. But after a lot of search I still doesn't understand how to use that in my case.

My starting code :

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string TextToDisplay { get; set; }
}
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Vehicule Vehicule{ get; set; }
    public Sector Sector{ get; set; }
}
public class Vehicule:IEntity
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
public class Sector:IEntity
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

What I saw is that the model of the partial view will look that :

`@model GenericModelType<IEntity>`

But now, what would the structure of `GenericModelType` and how to render partial view (what parameter to put in `@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView",?????)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your classes won't compile. Nothing in them is 'generic'. You didn't post `GenericModelType<>`.

Comment: Of course that's the question...

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be :

```
@model IEntity
```

and your render code :

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView", model);
```

To determine model type you can use "is" keyword :

```
if (model is Sector)
    // Do something
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vtxbSg) is good example for review.

Comment: MMhh, in this case, how my partial view knows that it's a `Vehicule` or `Sector` ?